# sql query to count and display full name

Tags: sql, oracle

So I am very confused by this query to display teachers' full name. I have used teacher_name ||' '|| teacher_lastname, but when I try to do so for the students, something happens. I am trying to get number of times a teacher had an appointment with a student and display teacher fullname and students full name. Below is my query :

```
select d.teacher_id ||' '|| d.teacher_lastname as Teacher,  count (distinct c.student_id)
from teacher d inner join class t on t.teacher_id=d.teacher_id
inner join classRoom tp on tp.dest_id=t.dest_id
inner join classFl ta on tp.dest_id=ta.dest_id
inner join students c on c.student_id=ta.student_id
group by d.teacher_id,d.teacher_lastname
```

[image]
This is the output, but when I add

```
select d.teacher_id ||' '|| d.teacher_lastname as Teacher,
c.student_name||' '||c.student_lastname as Student,
count (distinct c.student_id)
```

and also add it to the `group by d.teacher_id,d.teacher_lastname,c.customer_name,c.customer_lastname`

it gives the following result

[image]
What is wrong? How can I fix it to have the same nr of counts for each teacher?
I am using oracle sql developer

Comment: This looks [identical to your earlier, now deleted question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60332431/count-in-a-query/60332476#60332476).  Has something changed?

Comment: Nothing is wrong. The second results are the same as the first. Teacher `xxxx yyyy` saw 5 different students in the first grid (as indicated by the 5) and 5 different students in the second grid (as indicated by the 5 rows where each student name is different)

Comment: I wanted to edit smth and accidentlly deleted it. I added that i am using sql developer since before it had some confusions

Comment: What do the tables represent? At first I thought `classFl` is the class, but then I saw it contains a `student_id`. So, what is this table supposed to mean instead? What does a `dest_id` represent?

Comment: There's nothing wrong with your result. You got what you asked for. Now, if you want to count the student ids by teacher and still display one row per student, then you need to use analytical form of count: count(c.student_id) over (partition by d.teacher_id)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to remove the DISTINCT from inside the COUNT. You say you want "nr of times a teacher had an appointment with a student" which I interpret to mean that if teacher T saw student S 9 times you want:

```
T S 9
```

If you keep DISTINCT, then grouping on student name and counting the number of unique student IDs will only ever produce a 1 unless two students have identical names. In essence then, by keeping the DISTINCT you are counting "the number of different students with name X that that teacher met with" and mostly this is 1 because "1 unique student named Hana Baker met with xxxx yyyy", "1 unique student with name Dream Kenise met with xxxx yyyy" ....

If you do have students with the same name but a different ID, then you should add student ID to the GROUP BY to provide distinction between the two students. You don't have to add it to the SELECT, but you'll struggle to tell them apart if you do. If you have two students both called S, but one has ID 1 (and he saw T 5 times) and the other has ID 2 (and she saw T 4 times) you'll get a result of:

```
T S 5
T S 4
```

You might want to add other columns to your select to better tell the difference between them

---

In your first query, using DISTINCT meant "the number of different students that sought a meeting with the teacher". Omitting DISTINCT in that query would have counted "the number of times the teacher had a meeting with any student"